# Analyze poor MYSQL Query Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I wish to analyze poor MYSQL Query Performance which was happened in different time stamp.

In Oracle, I used to use sqlt (SQLTXPLAIN) report when it's required to analyze poor query performance before and after major version upgrade or executes a query with drastic execution variance in same environment with similar server load. It could provide why SQL is not performing as expected and crucial information (Performance history for the SQL statement, DB parameters, State of CBO stats, Changes on histograms, indexes compare including state, execution plan analysis and all) to actually find root causes before trying to fix performance issue.

Sample Oracle SQLT Report for the reference - http://carlossierradotnet1.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/sqlt_s60032_main.pdf

Can I produce similar report for the MYSQL query which executes with best execution time and worst performance occasionally in the same server environment?

**Update:**

Capturing long running query and analyze execution plan for a query doesn't work to resolve the problem that I have mentioned in the question. Query doesn't have any problem as it runs without any issue(less than a sec), rarely it behaves with worst performance(hangs sometimes). I am pretty sure, we could pin point the root cause if we get details of Performance history for the SQL statement, State of CBO stats, Changes on histograms, indexes compare including state, execution plan analysis and all for the same query in best and worst timestamp.

I don't have particular query here as it can happen with any complex query if they are running in a big batch, I'd like to provide scenario which might be helpful to understand the problem:

QUERY BATCH#1 - Complex Query#1; Query#2;....Query#10....Complex Query#N;

**Situation#1:** 
All queries are perfectly tuned and runs smoothly when they are executed one by one in a MYSQL prompt.

**Situation#2:** 
QUERY BATCH#1 executing smoothly every night smoothly on 01/05, 02/05, 04/05, 06/05/2014 but Query#2 was taking unacceptable execution time only on 03/05 and Query#10 was taking unacceptable execution time on 05/05/2014. Please be informed that issue was happened with different queries and resource usage (cpu, ram, n/w i/o, storage i/o, etc) and number of db connections are same every day.

Is there any way to check why optimizer took unacceptable time for Query#2 and Query#10 only on 03/05 and 05/05 respectively? Now a days QUERY BATCH#1 runs smoothly every day without applying any changes in the database/system/application.

Comment: Requests for resources/tools are off-topic here, I think because historically they have attracted spam answers. However, if you have a problematic query, edit this question to show it, plus your schema and explain plan, and perhaps people will make suggestions.

Comment: (As it stands, the question will close, but I think TOAD has a MySQL version. Look into that?)

Comment: As a first approach you can activate MYSQLs slow query log and check the outputs there. To activate it, just set slow_query_log=1 in your my.ini file and look into the file specified as slow_query_log_file.

Furthermore I agree with halfers comments above.

Comment: Thanks @halfer for the comment. My apology for asking the tool!!!

Comment: Capturing long running query and analyze execution plan for a query doesn't work to resolve the problem that I have mentioned in the question.

Query doesn't have any problem as it runs without any issue(less than a sec), rarely it behaves with worst performance(hangs sometimes). I am pretty sure, we could pin point the root cause if we get details of Performance history for the SQL statement, State of CBO stats, Changes on histograms, indexes compare including state, execution plan analysis and all for the same query in best and worst timestamp. FYI-SQLT reports gives those details in Oracle.

Comment: In that case, it is not at all clear from your question @Suresh that the issue is intermittent. Would you edit your question?

Comment: @halfer - I tried to explain more for the problem.

Comment: I've not done slow query logging, but can you turn that on and see if it has a detrimental effect? If it slows your queries by only a few percent, it will be worth it over a few days to get the data you need to debug this. Look at the manual too, to see if there is advice about how long it should be turned on for.

Comment: Aside from notes about no "tool" to do it... cant you just post the queries themselves to be reviewed.  Sometimes a second set of eyes MIGHT help you see some other alternative to your query.